# Wordpress main search widget - Search events

Tags: search

Does the search widget in wordpress integrate with CiviCRM.  I need for people in mi site to be able to search for events in a particular city. For example if I have an event in Miami and someone searches in main site for Miami all events in that city to show up.

Is that possible???

Answer (score 1):

If you use a short code for your event on a page and include the search terms you are looking for in the permalink it should be found in search results. So in your case you would create pages (or posts) for each event with the short code included  and include the city in the permalinks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is possible without additional coding work. My experience in Drupal would be a 'this is only possible via the Search API, or by creating nodes for each Event'.